# I can't fetch one row that comes from mysql database in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, fetch

I prepared two sql statements that runs on one sql connection. When I run them in phpMyAdmin - the first one returns one row, the second one - couple rows. However, when I use the following code in php:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
(...)
$sql1 = "SELECT ...";
$sql2 = "SELECT ...";

$result = $conn->query($sql1);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
    echo "INSIDE IF:: " . $row["end_time"];
        $variable = $row["end_time"];
    }
}
else{
    echo "FIRST ELSE";
    $variable = $sth;
}

$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "the 2nd statement worked"; (...)
}
```

I get on screen message: FIRST ELSE and the 2nd statement worked. Why I don't see "INSIDE IF"? I'm 100% positive that the first query returns one single row.

Comment: Print $result->num_rows somewhere before while loop and see how many rows are fetched

Comment: Akhil, I added in the code line print $resultpre->num_rows; just before the first if, but there's nothing printed, am I doing that correctly?

Comment: Check my answer, If that helped for you, do not forget to select It as correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if ($result = $conn->query($sql1)) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "INSIDE IF:: " . $row["end_time"];
        $variable = $row["end_time"];
    }       
    $result->free();
} else {
    echo "FIRST ELSE";
}
```